# Displaying Values of MYSQL Result via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, row

OK, this is an amateur question but I am having the most trouble displaying the values of my database. I want to display the entire 'phone' column so my mysql query is this:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT phone FROM contactList WHERE phone != 1') or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

My PHP script is as this:

```
while(isset($rows))
{
echo $rows['phone'] . "html break tag";
}
```

It looks like though I'm only getting the first result instead of looping through the entire column.

Do I need to increment the ID in my loop and get value via ID? The only problem with that is my auto-incremental ID column starts @ 130 and skips some numbers here and there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead

```
While($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  echo $row['phone'];
```

That should help you looping through the whole array.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee mysql_fetch_array() fetches all columns of one row into an array. In your case, one phone number ; )

Comment: Ohhhhh so by looping through all the rows I can pull the specific column that makes sense. Thanks!